# Java Swing -- Asking for User Input (and creating a blocking thread) by popping up a JFrame

Tags: java, events, swing

My top-level container is `MainFrame (JFrame)`. I want to be able to popup another JFrame with a JPanel that has two JTextFields from `MainFrame`.

The thing is: I need to be able to block the EDT from the Swing GUI. This is reminscent of using a JOptionPane to block the EDT until the user has either hit `OK` or `CANCEL`.

The question is: Is it possible to create a "custom" JOptionPane with user-defined values that will block the EDT?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into [`JDialog`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html)

You can extend `JDialog` and call super in your constructor with the second parameter set to `true`

```
super(parent, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a [JDialog](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html)

You can set it to be modal in this [JDialog(Frame, modal)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html#JDialog%28java.awt.Frame,%20boolean%29) constructor